# Planted New Elberta Peach Tree

Tags: plant-health, peaches

everybody!

I just planted an Elberta Peach tree that’s about a year old.
When I got it from the nursery, it had holes in the leaves but no bugs.  So I went and got some neem oil to spray it with.
Well.  It’s been in the 90s here.  I’m scared of over watering it, because everything I’ve seen says about once a week.  Even the lady from the nursery told me that.
But the leaves are turning yellow / falling off and the branches Are slightly brown, but still sturdy.

Help?  This tree was planted on the 4th, the day I was supposed to be giving birth to my son.  I don’t want it to die...

Comment: Did you spray it with the neem oil?

Comment: I did spray it with the neem oil.

Comment: So, did you rinse it off afterwards? This could be the cause of your issues if the tree is in full sun and in over 90 degree heat. As to watering, 1 inch/week is recommended (all at the same time, if possible). Watering deeply infrequently is much better than watering a little bit each day because it trains the roots to go deeper into the soil rather than staying near the surface. Also - what mulch as you using for the tree?